# Issues in setup of new Angular Project using Yeoman

Tags: gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

I am new to Yeoman and starting a new project

1. I installed Latest NodeJS 64 bit version (downloaded today), installed ruby, added ruby bin folder to path and installed compass with

   ```
   gem install compass --pre
   ```
2. I ran

   ```
   npm install -g yo
   ```
3. I ran

   ```
   yo angular
   ```
4. It was sucessfull
5. Now I run

   ```
   grunt serve
   ```
6. Above also works fine
7. Now I try

   ```
   grunt build
   ```

It fails to do a build and give me the below error

```
Running "concurrent:dist" (concurrent) task
    Warning:
    E:\RemoteRepoProjects\CRM\Application\ria-crm\node_modules\grunt-contrib-com
pass\node_modules\tmp\lib\tmp.js:261
      throw err;
            ^
    Error: spawn ENOENT
        at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
        at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34) Use --f
orce to continue.

    Aborted due to warnings.
```

Comment: I found out that this error was because of the latest version of compass and sass. I tried to install the old stable version and this issue is solved

Comment: Could you please give details of the versions and add that to the answer so that this question is marked as answered. Will be useful for future references.